# Using Omniture ActionSource with Flash IDE

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe-analytics

I have a flash app built in ActionScript 3 utilizing a document class.

I have followed the documentation for implementing Omniture ActionSource tracking by adding the ActionSource component to my fla's library, and then importing it into the document class and running the configuration code. However, the app fails to compile because it cannot resolve the path to the component (com.omniture.ActionSource).

My class path contains a com directory (package) where most of the classes I use in my projects reside.

Has anyone had success implementing ActionSource in this manner?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alpinista - make sure you are importing the class in your DocumentClass

```
import com.omniture.ActionSource;
```

And make sure you are adding the ActionSource class to the project by either using the mxp feature:

Command Menu > Omniture - Add ActionSource to Library

OR

You can add the ActionSource SWC file to your publish setting if you have CS4 or later:

File > Publish Setting > Flash > Settings... button > Library Path Tab > Click (+) button > Click Red Envelope button > Select the SWC file, then hit okay.

If you still can't publish, then you probably forgetting something even more simple, or have a typeo/syntax error.